# Visual Studio 2017 not able to resolve any using statements

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 (Enterprise, 15.6.6 at the moment), and no solution seems to load correctly anymore. A specific, simple repro on my environment is to open Visual Studio and create a new "ASP.NET Core Web Application (Visual C#)", subtype "API" without authentication or docker support.

If I then open `Startup.cs` I'm greeted with a screen filled with red squiggly lines under all `using` directives and corresponding usages of stuff from those namespaces:

[image: red squiggly lines everywhere]

If I restore NuGet packages it will say something along these lines:

> Restore completed in 52,93 ms for ....WebApplication1.csproj.

If I build the solution I get a bunch for errors about references not being found. I then checked the "Build" Output window and it says something along these lines:

```
------ Build started: Project: WebApplication4, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
[...] The "ResolveAssemblyReference" task failed unexpectedly.
[...] Microsoft.Build.Shared.InternalErrorException: MSB0001: Internal MSBuild Error: Unexpected CopyLocal flag.
[...]    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CopyLocalStateUtility.IsCopyLocal(CopyLocalState state)
[...]    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveAssemblyReference.LogResults(ReferenceTable dependencyTable, DependentAssembly[] idealAssemblyRemappings, AssemblyNameReference[] idealAssemblyRemappingsIdentities, ArrayList generalResolutionExceptions)
[...]    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveAssemblyReference.Execute(FileExists fileExists, DirectoryExists directoryExists, GetDirectories getDirectories, GetAssemblyName getAssemblyName, GetAssemblyMetadata getAssemblyMetadata, GetRegistrySubKeyNames getRegistrySubKeyNames, GetRegistrySubKeyDefaultValue getRegistrySubKeyDefaultValue, GetLastWriteTime getLastWriteTime, GetAssemblyRuntimeVersion getRuntimeVersion, OpenBaseKey openBaseKey, GetAssemblyPathInGac getAssemblyPathInGac, IsWinMDFile isWinMDFile, ReadMachineTypeFromPEHeader readMachineTypeFromPEHeader)
[...]    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveAssemblyReference.Execute()
[...]    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
[...]    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
1>Done building project "WebApplication4.csproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped  ==========
```

The abbreviated bit at the start of each line (not sure if it's relevant) is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2052,5): error MSB4018:
```

Now most likely something I've done recently caused this to appear. Some things I suspect are:

- I've updated the [Nuget.CommandLine](https://chocolatey.org/packages/NuGet.CommandLine) package from Chocolatey
- I've tried to do some .NET Core development in VSCode
- I've upgraded Visual Studio to the latest version (15.6.6)
- I've updated VSCode recently
- I run Windows Updates regularly
- I've updated NPM recently
- I recently had a BSOD while waking my laptop (which had Visual Studio open at the time)

I'm at a loss of what the problem could be, or more importantly: how I can find out what the problem is. *So my main question is: how do I attack this specific problem?* Failing that, my question is how to solve this situation (though I suspect there can be multiple causes).

Comment: Hmmm, right after posting I did a hail mary by shift-deleting my `C:\users\jeroen\.nuget\packages` folder's contents, and now the rebuilds are working again. Will investigate a bit more, but seems the answer to my secondary question was to purge that folder :/

Comment: `using` *directives*. C# has two different concepts that both employ the keyword `using`. One is called a using directive, the other is called a using statement. Using the name of one when you want to discuss the other can only lead to confusion.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thx, I wasn't aware of the distinction in terminology, makes sense. Learn something new every day! :D Edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After writing the question I did a few hail mary fixes, including purging this:

```
c:\users\jeroen\.nuget\packages\*.*
```

This technically only answers the *second* question. I'm posting this because it might help someone, but I'm still oblivious to the actual cause or a good heuristic for solving this type of issue, and would love to see another, better answer.

Comment: I could hug you!!! i had disk corruption that CHKDISK fixed, still no worky... i updated Visual Studio, re-installed .net SDK's, still no worky... your's was the ticket!!!

Comment: @neoscribe Thx for your comment, seems writing my answer down for others was 3 minutes well spent back in 2018 